# JOptionPane кнопки

Tags: java

Каким образом на JOptionPane можно оставить только кнопку Cancel, или присвоить кнопке Ok CANCEL_OPTION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбирай что больше подойдет =) [Sample JOptionPane in a JDialog](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SampleJOptionPaneinaJDialog.htm)